# How can I check s3 file uploaded or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I'm implementing a direct pdf file upload from client machine to Amazon S3 via REST API using only Go langangue, All works fine but one thing is worrying me...
Here is the steps

- User click on pdf button
- New browser tab is open there is in html page(which says generating
  your report)
- On background pdf file is uploading(in process) on s3. And API return s3
  url to client.

**Problem**

how can I check if the URL is active yet or not. If it's a 404 it doesn't redirect… waits another N seconds. Once it's a 200, then I redirect to s3 url.

How can I achieve this on javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS S3 ensures GET after PUT consistency for new objects. From https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/

"
**Q: What data consistency model does Amazon S3 employ?**

Amazon S3 buckets in all Regions provide read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects and eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES.
"

This ensures that once the upload is done, your object will be reachable. Now, with JS you can issue an Ajax request only if you're on same domain or you enable CORS on your S3 bucket. This is explained here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html and it will allow you to check your object on S3 being there.

Otherwise, you would need a server-side component to check if the object is uploaded and call that resource from JS on the same domain.